# List of characters to be restricted for protection against XSS and SQL Injections?

Tags: php, mysql, security, xss, sql-injection

I have gone through a lot of articles out there to find out a simple list of characters that can restrict a user from inputting for protecting my site against XSS and SQL Injections, but couldn't find any generic list as such.

Can someone help me out by simply giving me a list of safe or unsafe characters in this regard? I know this can be field specific but I need this for text field where I want to allow maximum possible characters.

Comment: thanks all for your responses. so, it seems that i will have to research a bit more into this as just white-listing characters is not gonna help.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The "black-list" approach is fraught with problems. For both SQLi and XSS, input validation against a white-list is essential i.e. define what you *do expect* rather than what you *don't expect*. Remember also that user input - or "untrusted data" - comes from many places: forms, query strings, headers, ID3 and exif tags etc.

For SQLi, make sure you're always using parametrised SQL statements, usually in the form of stored procedure parameters or any decent ORM. Also apply the "principal of least privilege" and limit the damage the account connecting to your database can do. More on SQLi here: http://www.troyhunt.com/2010/05/owasp-top-10-for-net-developers-part-1.html

On the XSS front, always encode your output and make sure you're encoding it for the appropriate markup language it appears in. Output encoding for JavaScript is different to HTML which is different to CSS. Remember to encode not just responses which immediately reflect input, but also untrusted data stored in the database which could hold a persistent XSS threat. More on all this here:  http://www.troyhunt.com/2010/05/owasp-top-10-for-net-developers-part-2.html

I know this goes a bit beyond your original question, but the point I'm trying to make is that allowable characters is but one small part of the picture. The other practices mentioned above are arguably more important (but you should still use those white-lists as well).

Comment: thanks for your answer. so the bottom-line is that just a white-list is not enough. but what i wanted to know is that, are there any characters apart from the alphanumeric characters that are never used in any attacks. like for example, what if i only allow alphanumeric text with dot (.) and comma (,) will that allow anyone to cause any harm?

Comment: Are there any characters today or are there any characters tomorrow? For today, have a look at the XSS cheat sheet and you'll how vast the attack structures can be: http://ha.ckers.org/xss.html For tomorrow, well, the whole point is that we don't know. There are constantly new exploits popping up so who knows what sort of zero-days are out there waiting to happen. This is why the white-list is so important; even if we don't *think* a particular character could be used maliciously, we may well turn out to be wrong over time.

Answer (score 5):

Character filtering is not how you should go about security. To prevent SQL injection, use [prepared statements](http://www.ultramegatech.com/blog/2009/07/using-mysql-prepared-statements-in-php/). To prevent XSS you should [escape](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_%28Cross_Site_Scripting%29_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet#XSS_Prevention_Rules) all user input properly

Comment: thanks for your response and the link but i don't want to go into the security stuff right now cause i don't have that much time :) can't i just simple avoid certain characters that are known to be used in such attacks?

Comment: I don't recommend you do it, but if you are going to do security by character filtering then you are better off whitelisting than blacklasting. I do not know enough about either SQL injection or XSS to give you a definitive answer as to which characters you need to ban in order to be completely secure (and there is no point banning any characters if you can be exploited with others), but banning quotes (both single and double) and angle brackets is good for a start, though almost certainly not sufficient.

Comment: Atul, if you really want to take short cuts, begin with parameterised SQL (you shouldn't be doing it any other way anyway), and output encoding. Do these properly and the white-list won't matter so much (but you *should* still implement this). Black-listing characters is a slippery slope which is almost always done laboriously and poorly with limited efficacy.

Answer (score 1):

Look at the [implementation](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--filter--filter.module/function/filter_xss/6) of xss filtering of Drupal CMS. The function has white list containing allowed HTML tags, all other stuff will be escaped.